# Convert UTC timezone to IST python

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, timezone, utc, python-datetime

The following code line gives me the **UTC** timing on the production server.

```
timestamp = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

Please suggest a way to convert above UTC timezone to **IST(Indian Standard Time)** timing.

Comment: If you want to get control of timezones, you should install the `tz` module (you see the link in Python standard library documentation (at end of section https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#tzinfo-objects). It is not included in Python (but a lot of discussion) because tz database requires frequent changes, much more frequent than Python releases).

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi: what is the *tz module*? In the docs you linked, there's a link to `dateutil` and the IANA database.

Comment: @MrFuppes: the module you used in your answer `dateutils.tz`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime    
import pytz    
tz_NY = pytz.timezone('Asia/Kolkata')   
datetime_NY = datetime.now(tz_NY)  
print("India time:", datetime_NY.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f"))       
>>India time: 2021-05-03 12:25:21.877976
```

Answer (score 16):

`datetime.now()` gives you a naive datetime object that represents local time according to the setting of the machine you run the script on (which in this case *just happens to be UTC* since it's a server). See the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.now).

To get "now" in a specific timezone, you can set the `tz` property appropriately.

**Python >= 3.9:** you have [zoneinfo](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/zoneinfo.html) in the standard lib to do this:

```
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo
dtobj = datetime.now(tz=ZoneInfo('Asia/Kolkata'))
print(dtobj)
>>> 2020-07-23 11:11:43.594442+05:30
```

**Python < 3.9:** I'd recommend the [dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) package to do so (or use  `zoneinfo` via [backports.zoneinfo](https://pypi.org/project/backports.zoneinfo/)).

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.tz import gettz
dtobj = datetime.now(tz=gettz('Asia/Kolkata'))
print(dtobj)
>>> 2020-07-23 11:08:54.032651+05:30
```

Comment: Can you suggest a method that does not use +5:30 at the end of the string and provides the true time? Thanks in advance

Comment: @GarvitJoshi you mean print/get a string without the UTC offset? You can e.g. `dtobj.strftime("%d %b %y, %H:%M:%S")`, is that what you need? See [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) for more formatting directives.